# ¿Será por la extensión php?

Tags: php, html, css, cpanel

Tengo un dominio en cpanel, pero igual tengo otros subdominios, al momento de subir un nuevo proyecto en vez de solo poner [www.pagina.com](http://www.pagina.com) para que me lleve a mi sitio web, tengo que poner [www.pagina.com/index.php](http://www.pagina.com/index.php) y es que solo con archivos php me sucede, yo quiero que con solo poner mi dominio, me lleve a mi sitio web.

Comment: Apache, Nginx o IIS?

Comment: Estoy usando Apache

Comment: Revisa [esta página](https://bobcares.com/blog/how-to-change-default-index-page-in-cpanel/) (en inglés), menciona como hacer que `index.php` sea el documento por defecto en cPanel.